# Why this.name is returned as undefined in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```
function returnName() {
    var name = 'Stack Overflow'
    console.log(this.name)
}
```

When I call this function, instead of printing the name **'Stack Overflow'** Google Chrome console is returning **'undefined'**.

Why is this behaviour? As I have read this keyword always refer to the current execution context then why it is not returning the name?

Comment: Because that is not how `this` works. `console.log(name)` works.

Comment: ```this===window``` window object is above your function scope and does not contain the field name on it

Answer (score 1):

You didn't add name to `this` object:

```js
function returnName() {
    this.name = 'Stack Overflow'
    console.log(this.name)
}
```

If you want to create a variable and log it in `returnName`, you don't need `this`:

```js
function returnName() {
    var name = 'Stack Overflow'
    console.log(name)
}
```